# What is meant by Routine escrow mechanism in buying and selling process within a decentralized platform?

Tags: decentralization

As we know for buyers in the crypto-exchange, they are protected by routine escrow mechanisms , what does that actually mean?

Comment: Same question: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/9085/what-are-routine-escrow-mechanisms

Answer (score 1):

It generally means your funds are sent to a multi signature wallet with the exchange. Allowing the exchange to settle any dispute with 2 of three involved parties: you, counterparty, exchange